# Pandas read_csv file importing error

Tags: python, csv, encoding, pandas

I am trying to import a csv file in Pandas but it throws an error. The format of the data when opened in notepad++ is as follows with first row being column names:

```
"End Customer Organization ID,End Customer Organization Name,End Customer Top Parent Organization ID,End Customer Top Parent Organization Name,Reseller Top Parent ID,Reseller Top Parent Name,Business,Rev Sum Division,Rev Sum Category,Product Family,Version,Pricing Level,Summary Pricing Level,Detail Pricing Level,MS Sales Amount,MS Sales Licenses,Fiscal Year,Sales Date"
"11027676,Baroda Western Uttar Pradesh Gramin Bankgfhgfnjgfnmjmhgmghmghmghmnghnmghnmhgnmghnghngh,4078446,Bank Of Barodadfhhgfjyjtkyukujkyujkuhykluiluilui;iooi';po'fserwefvegwegf,1809012,""Hcl Infosystems Ltd - Partnerdghftrutyhb frhywer5y5tyu6ui7iukluyj,lgjmfgnhfrgweffw"",Server & CALsdgrgrfgtrhytrnhjdgthjtyjkukmhjmghmbhmgfngdfbndfhtgh,SQL Server & CALdfhtrhtrgbhrghrye5y45y45yu56juhydsgfaefwe,SQL CALdhdfthtrutrjurhjethfdehrerfgwerweqeadfawrqwerwegtrhyjuytjhyj,SQL CALdtrye45y3t434tjkabcjkasdhfhasdjkcbaksmjcbfuigkjasbcjkasbkdfhiwh,2005,Openfkvgjesropiguwe90fujklascnioawfy98eyfuiasdbcvjkxsbhg,Open Lklbjdfoigueroigbjvwioergyuiowerhgosdhvgfoisdhyguiserhguisrh,""Open Stddfm,vdnoghioerivnsdflierohgushdfovhsiodghuiohdbvgsjdhgouiwerho"",125.85,1,FY07,12/28/2006"
"12835756,Uttam Strips Pvt Ltd,12835756,Uttam Strips Pvt Ltd,12565538,Redington C/O Fortis Financial Services Ltd,MBS,Dynamics ERP,Dynamics NAV,Dynamics NAV Business Essentials,Non-specific,Other,MBS SA,MBS New Customer Enhanc. Def,0,0,FY09,9/15/2008"
"12233135,Bhagwan Singh Tondon,12233135,Bhagwan Singh Tondon,2652941,H B S Systems Pvt Ltd,Server & CAL,SQL Server & CAL,SQL CAL,SQL CAL,Non-specific,Open,Open L&SA,Deferred Open L&SA - New,0,0,FY09,9/15/2008"
"11602305,Maya Academy Of Advanced Cinematics,9750934,Maya Entertainment Ltd,336146,Embee Software Pvt Ltd,Server & CAL,Windows Server & CAL,Windows Server HPC,Windows Compute Cluster Server,Non-specific,Open,Open V/MYO - Rec,OLV Perpet L&SA Recur-Def,0,0,FY09,9/25/2008"
"13336009,Remiel Softech Solution Pvt Ltd,13336009,Remiel Softech Solution Pvt Ltd,13335482,Redington C/O Remiel Softech Solutions Pvt Ltd,MBS,Dynamics ERP,Dynamics NAV,Dynamics NAV Business Essentials,Non-specific,Other,MBS SA,MBS New Customer Enhanc. Def,0,0,FY09,12/23/2008"
"7872800,Science Application International Corporation,2839760,GOVERNMENT OF KARNATAKA,10237455,Cubic Computing P.L,Server & CAL,SQL Server & CAL,SQL Server Standard,SQL Server Standard Edition,Non-specific,Open,Open SA/UA,Deferred Open SA - Renewal,0,0,FY09,1/15/2009"
"13096361,Pratham Software Pvt Ltd,13096361,Pratham Software Pvt Ltd,10133086,Krap Computer,Information Worker,Office,Office Standard / Basic,Office Standard,2007,Open,Open L,Open Std,7132.44,28,FY09,9/24/2008"
"12192276,Texmo Precision Castings,12192276,Texmo Precision Castings,4059430,Quadra Systems. - Partner,Server & CAL,Windows Server & CAL,Windows Standard Server,Windows Server Standard,Non-specific,Open,Open L&SA,Deferred Open L&SA - New,0,0,FY09,11/15/2008"
```

**Kindly note that the same file when double clicked in the csv format opens in excel with comma separated values BUT with NO quotation marks in each line as shown in notepad++.**

I have used encoding as UTF-8 which gives the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 13: invalid start byte
```

Then used encoding='cp1252' first and then tried with latin1.

```
df=pd.read_csv(filename,encoding='cp1252') 

or 

df=pd.read_csv(filename,encoding='latin1')
```

With both the encodings it didn't give any error and the data got imported but as one single column and not as different columns.

Does it have to do with the "" marks present before each line in the data? I had a similar csv file with comma separated values, but that didn't have double quotation marks in each line and that got imported correctly both with cp1252 and latin1. But not for UTF-8 even though the file was saved in utf8 format in notepad++. But in this case utf8 doesnt work as usual and other two import it as single column.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Why is every line enclosed in quotation marks? Just remove those and the import should work fine.

Comment: @DominicKexel Yeah that's what. On opening the file in notepad++ I see that it has every line in quotes. Maybe that might be preventing the encoding. So my question was i) Is there an encoding which can take care of the quotes too. ii) If not, then how to remove the quotes in each line? 

Thanks

Comment: @DominicKexel Hi, I was hoping if you could help with this as I have tried almost all the options I could find in read_csv function of pandas but it doesn't resolve the quote problem above or read as separate columns if encoding='latin1' or encoding='cp1252'. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the quotation marks cause it to interpret all the commas within as escaped. So, you need to strip all of them off. That's relatively simple to do, but because of the unicode issues I'm going to be crazy and suggest you read it in, strip the quotes and then write it to a file to use with `read_csv` (because it'll simplify the encoding issues).

Here's how to write to a file and strip the quotes, write to a new file, then read in with read_csv:

```
with open(filename) as infile, open(tmpfile, 'wb') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.strip('"'))

result = pd.read_csv(tmpfile, encoding='cp1252')
```

You'd want to remove the temporary file after you're done reading it in too.

The reason I suggest doing it like the above because you get to avoid dealing with encoding/decoding when passing to a StringIO buffer - can be finicky for both Python and pandas.